# Сравнение 2 массивов в GO

Tags: массивы, golang

Имеем 2 массива для примера:
t := []int{1,2,3,4,5}
s := []int{3,2,4}
Нужно сравнив 2 этих массива определить каких значении в s не хватает и добавить отсутствующие например в массив d.

Comment: Что вас не устраивает в простом использовании `map` для этой цели?

Comment: Задача найти отсутствующие элементы массива. Впринципе разницы особой невижу делать это в мапе или в массиве.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой вариант с `map`:

```
sm := make(map[int]struct{}, len(s))
for _, n := range s {
    sm[n] = struct{}{}
}
var d []int
for _, n := range t {
    if _, ok := sm[n]; !ok {
        d = append(d, n)
    }
}

fmt.Println(d)
// [1 5]
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/-WDtEET1L6.

Comment: Спасибо! По ходу Вы единственный знаток Go на этой площадке)